# Python request to retrieve all requests from Postman collection

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, postman

I need to print all requests from specific Postman collection. I have this code:

```
import requests

# Set up Postman API endpoint and authorization
postman_api_endpoint = "https://api.getpostman.com/collections"
postman_api_key = "PMAK-63b6bf724ebf902ad13d4bf2-e683c12d426716552861acda**********"
headers = {"X-Api-Key": postman_api_key}

# Get all requests from Postman collection
collection_id = "25184041-c1537769-f598-4c0e-b8ae-8cd185a79c03"
response = requests.get(f"{postman_api_endpoint}/{collection_id}/items", headers)

if response.status_code != 200:
    print("Error retrieving collection:", response.text)
else:
    # Print all requests
    requests_data = response.json()["items"]
    for request_data in requests_data:
        request_method = request_data["request"]["method"]
        request_url = request_data["request"]["url"]
        request_headers = request_data["request"]["header"]
        request_body = request_data["request"]["body"]["raw"] \
            if request_data["request"]["body"]["mode"] == "raw" else ""
        print(f"{request_method} {request_url}")
        print("Headers:")
        for header in request_headers:
            print(f"{header['key']}: {header['value']}")
        print("Body:")
        print(request_body)
```

I received an error while I try to call response.text and have such massage:

**Error retrieving collection: {"error":{"name":"notFound","message":"Requested resource not found"}}**

Which means that I have 404 error. I have several assumptions what I did wrong:

1. I entered incorrect api key(But I checked several times and regenerated it twice)
2. I entered incorrect collection id, but in the screen below you can see where I took it and it is correct
   [image]
3. And as I think the most likely variant I wrote incorrect request where I put my key and my collection id(I din't find any example how such requests should be like)

And of course I have requests in my collection, so error can not be because the collection is empty

Please give me some advice how I can fix this error. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is actually is really simple. I didn't know that I need to push button save request in Postman. I think if I create request in collection it will automatically save it. But I didn't, so I just saved all requests manually and finally receive correct response.